# Mock node.js modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, integration-testing

Lets say I have this situation (architecture)

```
layer1 -> layer2 -> layer3
```

layers are just normal node.js modules (have some functions that are exported)

Layer1 requires layer2 and calls his functions and layer2 requires layer3 and calles his functions.

I want to test functions in layer1 but also mock layer3 (my function call in layer1 is propagated to layer3 and this one I want to mock).

What is the best way to do this?
I have looked at this module : https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire but I don't think it supports mocking when things are going 2 or more level in depth like my example.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: why do you think it proxyquire would not work 3 levels deep?

Comment: As I saw in documentation and with my example you have to have instance of that mocked module (var foo = proxyquire('./foo', { 'path': pathStub });)  ... but I can't get to that layer3 module from my test because I don't test him... if you have some example (source or pseudocode) please write it :)

Comment: does layer2 require layer3 like this: require('module3') or require('./module3')?

Comment: Mocking modules in NodeJS can be really tricky sometimes, because it makes it easy to fall into a dependency HELL. I suggest you try to bind loosely your modules with a DI micro framework such as [c9-architect](https://github.com/c9/architect). I found it a lot easier to test my code once I started to organize it this way, and node modules that are installed from **npm** can be injected into your code, without requiring explicitly, by using the *options* parameter.

Comment: AndyD: it is require('./module3'). Modules are not in package.json but only in my code so it is relative path to them.

Comment: Naor: Sounds interesting, I will look at your suggestion but currently we have many lines of code so this kind of refactoring would take some time.

Comment: Ivan, if you haven't got module3 in that location, why not create a file with that name and all the correct function signatures like the real module3 ?

Comment: @ivan_zd We also use a dependency injection very similar to arhitect. Even though it adds a little boilerplate to the code, but never had problem with it. And it is very easy to override a dependency to a mock object.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery) with great success, although it can get really tedious depending on what you want to mock.

However, your setup seems kinda wacky. If you want to unit test layer 1, you should only need to mock layer 2, and there shouldn't be any (direct) connection between layer 1 and layer 3.

Comment: we are doing integration testing actually. See my answer to my own question, there is problem explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I was wrong with proxyquire. Yes, you can mock some module in 2 or more depth below your original module you are testing and it works fine as they showed in their example. Just put stub with path to that module which you are mocking. If you are mocking layer3, path of stub must be the same as the path to layer3 written in layer2 (so it is relative to layer2, not layer1 or some root).

We are doing integration testing and its difficult because we are using mongoDB database and there is no embedded database for mongo. There are some tries and alternatives but as I saw they are not good enough. So there was a root of my problems, we had to mock entire data layer.

Before that we had real database on some machine and integration tests on CI server (Jenkins) were using that real database but that is not very good because you cannot run tests on your laptop for example.

So mocking entire data layer of application is also very bad solution but as I see there is no alternatives. If anyone had the same or similar situation feel free to write your solution here.